# How to issue GET request to Google from an ESP32? (can't get it to work)

Tags: arduino, get, esp32

I´m trying to get an ESP32 to send GET requests to Google, but all I get is a -1 error response from the server. I'm using the Arduino IDE for this.

The reason behind the query to google is to get a basic setup on the ESP32 working. Based on that I will then need to modify it so that it sends a GET to our company's application running on App Engine.

After establishing a connection to my WiFi, I have the following code to generate the GET request:

```
if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
  HTTPClient http;

        
  // Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
  http.begin("google.com");
  
  // Send HTTP GET request
  int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
  
  if (httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println(payload);
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  // Free resources
  http.end();
}
else {
  Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Once I have a way to get the above working, I would like to send a query to google. Would the following be the right way?

```
      http.begin("google.com?search=ESP32");
```

Thanks!

**Edited after first feedback:**
I changed the following line to include full URI:

```
  // Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
  http.begin("google.com");
```

And now I get a 404 error:

HTTP Response code: 404

That’s an error
The requested URL `./1.1` was not found on this server.  That’s all we know

(Omitted the css tags for brevity)

Comment: see the BasicHttpsClient example of the HTTPClient library

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [example code](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpClient/BasicHttpClient.ino), then you'll notice that it specifies the address as an absolute URI (`http://example.com/index.html`), not a domain name only (`example.com`).

```
        http.begin("http://example.com/index.html"); //HTTP
```

Comment: Hi Tarmo, I added the http://  (also tried with https:// ) and now I get a 404 error (see above). At least I reached the server. Now I need to solve how to create a correct request.

Comment: In order to establish a https connection, you need to use the code from this [example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino).